# How to browse methods,classes,values within a library,api or a framework in Intellij?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, ide, lagom

The below picture is the code for lagom framework, now browsing within that file is not working as it should like in your project.
Here on Ctrl click on **LagomServiceBinder** is showing as **No usages found in Project Files**, I am not using in my Project file,yes, but I want to know where it is used withing that file or framework or API.
As **LagomServiceBinder** is also used below as **new LagomServiceBinder**, but it is not showing when Ctrl clicked.

[image: Showing No Usage]

Comment: Does it find the usages if you follow the hint and search in the project + libraries?

Comment: @CrazyCoder ,Yes even after Ctrl+Alt+7, it shows the same

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL with the sample attached.

Comment: @phineas consider cloning https://github.com/lagom/lagom/ and importing that. Then, you can text-search for `LagomServiceBinder` and find all the usages. I suggest you use `text-search` because `LagomServiceBinder` is code referenced from Scala macros (not regular scala code).